What does 年頃 mean in terms of marrigeable age and adulthood?
I read this and it uses that phrase and was wondering what does it mean regarding marrigeable age? does it mean adulthood?

ルーシィだってお年頃！！今はまだ…小説の中の恋愛しか知らないけれど、いつかは誰かと恋をしたい！？その時の相手は誰なのか…身近な仲間から、その可能性を勝手に妄想♡


お年頃 in this context refers to the age or period which one gains interest in dating or finding romantic partners.

doesn't it mean marriegeable age?

@ZainAlleck Yes, it works as well. Please see the monolingual definition for 年頃. The one we are talking about corresponds to entries 2 or 3.

@ZainAlleck I think the answer is most accurate. 年頃 is the most primitive word to say "coming of age", whose principal sense is the start of puberty, but in ancient times usually equated with marriageability and adulthood.

@JimmyYang I see so does its usage mean the character is an adult then or someone is an adult then?

@broccoliforest  I see so does its usage mean the character is an adult then or someone is an adult then?

@ZainAlleck "Adult" is a culture-dependent word. It is just my probabilistic guess but I think ルーシィ is most likely a low teen girl.

@broccoliforest no she's an adult. Why do you say low teen girl

@ZainAlleck He said that this is his guess, so it is not like he made a statement.

@JimmyYang why a guess

@JimmyYang I wonder cuz the translation uses marriage here https://imgur.com/a/Y1pjQXy and it says for now, which means there is a limit for marriage or something so doesn't it refer to marriage?

@ZainAlleck Only thing I can surely point is that saying お年頃 with お would be likely taken as child(ish) talk nowadays. Adult (in today's definition) or not is not described in this word itself but only context can disambiguate, as much as "brother" does not imply either he is an older or younger sibling.

@broccoliforest what do you mean childish talk?

@ZainAlleck The prefix お makes the word sound softer. As one of consequences, it is often used in speech by/to children and has such connotation.

@broccoliforest so does it mean lucy is not an adult?

@broccoliforest also what age range do you believe for Lucy?

@ZainAlleck If you think that Lucy is an adult, feel free to do so.

@JimmyYang how?

@broccoliforest when you say to children do you mean about children?
